# Анализ требований в вакансиях к программистам

Tags: работа

Время от времени читаю вакансии для программистов и веб-программистов. Часто встречаю такие тексты, подобно этому:

> - Навыки работы с системами контроля версий (SVN, git).
> - Опыт работы в трекерах задач (JIRA, mantis, redmine).

Или вот еще:

> - Практиковать и развивать практики code review.

Еще интересные цитаты из вакансий работодателей для веб-программистов:

> - Создание посадочных страниц (landing
>     page).
> - Опыт работы с parallax эффектами;
> - Хорошее понимание принципов    юзабилити, семантической верстки;

Кто может достаточно популярно объяснить эти высказывания и/или дополнить еще возможным списком требований в ведущих компаниях?

Comment: на данный момент не уметь работать с системами контроля версий это как не уметь говорить на английском. Если честно посмотреть на все эти "нетривиальные требования", то выясниться, что половина из них - это обычные базовые требования-уменья (как если бы для водителя маршрутки писали "уметь поворачивать ключ зажигания, давить педаль тормоза, различать цвета").

Comment: +1, я бы даже сказал что если это указывается специально, то скорее всего коллектив в целом неопытен или ищут среди не слишком опытных спецов - едва ли удастся найти более-менее приличного программера вне зависимости от направления, который бы не работал с чем-то из этого списка (ну кроме последнего - оно действительно узкоспециально)

Comment: В веб-программировании я недавно, потому немного смущает фраза "системы контроля версий". Обычно как делаешь, просто пишешь код исходя из версии языков программирования и СУБД, если что-то устаревшее не используешь это или переписываешь на новый лад и т.д. А когда системы контроля версий, это что автоматическая система анализа версии программного кода или как?

Comment: @IntegralAL, системы контроля версий предназначены, как ни странно, для контроля версий:) Например, они позволяют отследить, что какие (кем, когда) были внесены изменения, что все вдруг поломалось. И кстати они не совсем автоматические, в том смысле, что программист делает несколько изменений, и сам говорит этой системе, что эти изменения нужно зафиксировать.

Comment: А версий программных продуктов, а не версий используемых языков программирования). Ясно). Ну на примере веб-сайта например, есть десяток исполняемых файлов php и плюс еще два-три конфигурационных. Например сайт построен по MVC модели, есть классы, есть контроллеры и вьюверы (в которых еще примешан код Javascript и JQuery к примеру). С помощью систем версий контроля фиксируются все изменения сделанные в разных файлах в сравнении с определенной датой и предусматривается откат данных в случае надобности? Интегрируется как-то система версий контроля с веб-сервером или как-то отдельно?

Comment: * Сначала файлы добавляются. Это первоначальное состояние. Дальше делаются изменения, потом они фиксируются (коммитятся). Это следующее состояние. И и.д. Идет сравнение не между состояниями на определенную дату, а между ревизиями/наборами изменений. Можно откатывать изменения назад. Можно вести разработку в нескольких ветках. Можно сливать ветки вместе.
* Система контроля версий идет "как-то отдельно". Возможна интеграция в плане автоматического обновления файлов на хостинге при изменениях в репозитории.

Comment: нужно говорить по простому. Понятно, что обычный программист, который не использует систему контроля версий (СКВ) время от времени делает бекап исходников, что бы можно было попробовать сделать новую фичу или исправить баг. И делает этот бекап хоть с помощью Ctrl+C Ctrl+V или "undo-redo". СКВ позволяет автоматизировать этот процесс и прицепить кучу плюшек.

Comment: Надо же какие зверские требования. Небось еще эти гады не хотят платить сразу 150 тыр ни разу нигде не работавшему программисту. Профсоюза на них нет!

Comment: 150тыс.руб и никто платить не будет, если не живешь в Москве, а в регионах. Максимально я пока видел зарплату 80тыс.руб для веб-программиста, но там реально крутые требования, что до них мне еще расти надо, потому что веб-программированием занимаюсь меньше года. В среднем в регионе моем веб-программист получает 20-35тыс.руб. А вообще стаж программиста у меня 8 лет (прикладное программирование+ базы данных).

Comment: @IntegralAL, ну, я думаю, что люди выдвигающие такие требования за такие деньги (если они в здравом уме) реально имеют в виду, что претендент просто не испугается "страшных" терминов и согласится хоть о чем-то с ними поговорить :)

А если серьезно, то скорее всего, работодатель сам не очень компетентен (просто набрался где-то слов и блещет ими).

Comment: @IntegralAL 8 лет стаж, и при этом вы так удивляетесь вполне обыным требованиям работодателя? Выглядит странно

Comment: @DreamChild, я в команде программистов не работал, программист один был на работе, потом удаленно еще работал, потому не задумывался над термином практика code review, это просто было неактуально. Системы контроля версий тоже не использовал, просто делал бекапы исходников и архивы запасные. Трекеры задач тоже ни к чему, это обычно бывает когда очень много проектов рабочих и надо следить за исполнением их, сроками, это больше подходит для больших компаний или коллективных проектов. А термин "посадочные страницы" вообще присущ для веб-программистов, потому я его не знал, теперь буду знать).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> нетривиальными требованиями работодателей

Что тут нетривиального? Опыт работы с VCS подразумевает понимание хотя бы таких вещей как коммиты, ветки и слияния. И того, как они влияют на вашу работу и работу коллег. А может быть вы вообще гуру GIT-а и сможете предложить компании более оптимальную схему работы с ветками.

Опыт работы с таск-трекерами тоже базовый навык. Он говорит о том, что вы не будете спрашивать у коллег, что писать в поле "Описание", можете дать задаче адекватное название и понимаете, зачем все это нужно.

> Практиковать и развивать практики code review.

Code review - это просмотр чужого кода и его рецензирование. Где-то это делают при помощи дополнительных инструментов ([Crucible](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview), [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)), где-то скидывают рецензию на почту. По результатам инспектирования могут откатить ваш коммит в VCS (см. пункт 1). Если вы видте это в требованиях по вакансии - вам нужно уметь читать чужой код, понимать, что он делает и что с ним не так, выявлять bad practices.

> Создание посадочных страниц (landing page).

Это уже более узкий навык, специфичный для веб-разработки. Посмотрите, что такое [landing page](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Comment: то есть, лендинг-страница - это просто обыденная рекламная страница с низкосортным спамом и фишингом? (с точки зрения программиста).

Comment: вроде того ) Это страница, которая должна убедить покупателя сразу купить один конкретный товар/услугу. Желательно в один клик. [Несколько примеров](http://www.instapage.com/templates/).

Comment: @Nofate ♦ 

      Это страница, которая должна убедить покупателя сразу купить один конкретный товар/услугу. 

Что-то мне вспоминается, что "добрым словом и парабеллумом можно добиться гораздо большего, чем только добрым словом" (извините за неточность цитаты)

Comment: @Nofate ♦, нет, это все таки форма фишинга, так как она помогает впихнуть товар, который покупателю не нужен. При этом использует обманные пути.

Comment: @KoVadim, фишинг - это когда кто-то прикидывается ресурсом, которому пользователь доверяет дабы выманить у него конфиденциальные данные. Например, зашли вы на какой-нибудь http://vkontrakte.fake, а там форма входа и дизайн, как у ВК.  Вот это фишинг.


А когда вам говорят "Купите прямо сейчас и получите шесть штук по цене пяти, вот отзывы покупателей (хоть и фэйковые), а вот вам кнопка, кликайте" - это просто маркетинг. Как и любая технология лэндинг может использоваться мошенниками, продающими уникальную методику увеличения чего-нибудь (думаю, все видели подобные одностраничники).

Comment: я в курсе, что такое фишинг. Посмотрите на эти же страницы. Они выпрашивают у меня конфиденциальные данные. В многих случая можно было бы сократить до емейла или телефона и имени. А обман они скрывают глубже. Да, получить шесть по цене пяти, но цена то другая, и пять, не то что шесть предметов никогда человеку сразу и не нужна. И так дальше.

Я люблю эти маркетологов, которые переставляют товары в обычных магазинах, якобы после этого будет лучше продаваться. А потом бегаешь по всему магазину и ищешь нужный товар. И видишь ещё десяток таких, которые в шоке.